# How to cut and paste a part of an image randomly to a different location using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tensor

I am trying to implement a custom layer in keras.layers where I want to do a custom image augmentation. My idea is to cut out a part of an image from a random location and paste it to a different random location in the same image. The code below I have written works well for PIL Image but when I integrate it into my final code (which is a tensorflow model), I get as error saying that tensor doesn't support item assignment.

Below is the class that I have implemented:

```
class Cut_Paste(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, x_scale = 10, y_scale = 10, IMG_SIZE = (224,224), **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

        """
        defining the x span and the y span of the box to cutout
        x_scale and y_scale are taken as inputs as % of the width and height of the image
        size
        """        
        self.size_x, self.size_y = IMG_SIZE
        self.span_x = int(x_scale*self.size_x*0.01)
        self.span_y = int(y_scale*self.size_y*0.01)
        
    #getting the vertices for cut and paste    
    def get_vertices(self):
        
        #determining random points for cut and paste 
        """ since the images in the dataset have the object of interest in the center of 
        the Image, the cutout will be taken from the central 25% of the image"""
        fraction = 0.25
        vert_x = random.randint(int(self.size_x*0.5*(1-fraction)),
                               int(self.size_x*0.5*(1+fraction)))        
        vert_y = random.randint(int(self.size_y*0.5*(1-fraction)),
                               int(self.size_y*0.5*(1+fraction)))
        
        start_x = int(vert_x-self.span_x/2)
        start_y = int(vert_y-self.span_y/2)
        end_x = int(vert_x+self.span_x/2)
        end_y = int(vert_y+self.span_y/2)
        
        return start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y
        
    def call(self, image):
        
        #getting random vertices for cutting
        cut_start_x, cut_start_y, cut_end_x, cut_end_y = self.get_vertices()
        
        #getting the image as a sub-image
        #image = tf.Variable(image)
        sub_image = image[cut_start_x:cut_end_x,cut_start_y:cut_end_y,:]
        
        #getting random vertices for pasting
        paste_start_x, paste_start_y, paste_end_x, paste_end_y = self.get_vertices()
        
        #replacing a part of the image at random location with sub_image
        image[paste_start_x:paste_end_x,
              paste_start_y:paste_end_y,:] = sub_image
        
        return image
```

I am calling it from my model class this way:

```
class Contrastive_learning_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cut_paste = Cut_Paste(**cut_paste_augmentation)

    def train_step(self, data):
        augmented_images_2 = self.cut_paste.call(images)
```

I have removed the part of the code which is irrelevant. But upon executing this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

I understood from other sources that it is not possible to do item assignment in tensor. So here I am seeking help to do this in an easier way. I need to use tensors for this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [`RandomCrop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/RandomCrop), [`blend`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/blend) and [`translate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/translate) could help you

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow does not support item assignment unlike PyTorch.
A workaround you can implement is to convert the tensor to tf.Variable and then a numpy array like the following:

```
image = tf.Variable(image).numpy()
```